# timestamp format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want date format of `2014-07-24 17:35:00` to `24-07-2014 17:35:00` using JavaScript.

I tried this way,

```
datestring = '2014-07-24 17:35:00';

function formatDate(datestring) {
    var m_names = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
    var d = new Date(datestring);
    //var d = new Date(datestring * 1000);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var result = curr_date + "-" +m_names[curr_month]  + "-" + curr_year+' '+hours+':'+minutes;
    alert(result);
    return result;
}
```

But I am getting an error, `NaN-undefined-NaN NaN:NaN`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you multipling string by 1000?

Comment: new Date("2014-07-24 17:35:00" * 1000) -> Invalid Date

Comment: i tried  //var d = new Date(datestring); this way also

Comment: if it's available for you, try to use http://momentjs.com/ it's realy powerfull tool to work with dates

Comment: new Date("2014-07-24 17:35:00") -> Thu Jul 24 2014 17:35:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/UBLbQ/

Comment: Yes.. I got answer, i replace the string **datestring = '2014-07-24 17:35:00';** To **datestring = '2014/07/24 17:35:00';** then  it's work perfectly .. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you have simple way to solve this question.

Try this.

```
function myFunction() {

      var d = new Date("2014-07-24 17:35:00");
      var n = d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
      var t = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
      var r = n.replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'),'-')
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = replase +" "+t; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and look what I found

```
var datestring = '2014-07-24 17:35:00';

$("#date").val(formatDate1())
$("#date2").val(formatDate())

function formatDate1(datestring) {
var m_names = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
  var d = new Date(datestring);
  //var d = new Date(datestring * 1000);
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth();
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var result = curr_date + "-" +m_names[curr_month]  + "-" + curr_year+' '+hours+':'+minutes;

  return result;
}

function formatDate() {
  var m_names = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
  var d = new Date(datestring);
  //var d = new Date(datestring * 1000);
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth();
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var result = curr_date + "-" +m_names[curr_month]  + "-" + curr_year+' '+hours+':'+minutes;

  return result;
}
```

So your problem is parameter "datestring" because it's hiding variable with same name

here you can see an [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/dc9yh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A solution bellow with less code:

```js
function transformDate(dateString) {
  var dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' ');
  var dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('-');
  return [[dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0], ].join('-'), dateTimeParts[1]].join(" ");
}

var newDate = transformDate('2014-07-24 17:35:00');
console.log(newDate);
```

If you need more flexibility in your code, including working with localization you could consider [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library as well.